# Типы придаточных

Tags: синтаксис, спп, тип-придаточных

Какое (какие) из предложений имеет (имеют) одинаковые придаточные и почему?

1. Саша так устал, что сразу же лег спать, так что в гости мы пошли без него.
2. Сколько я ни пытался, я так и не смог сосчитать, сколько человек пришло на собрание.
3. На замечание, что перед едой надо мыть руки, мальчик ответил, что вымыл.
4. Он бежал намного быстрее, чем бегал раньше, словно за ним кто-то гнался.

(Или, быть может, здесь вообще нет одинаковых?)

Comment: Это не д/з, а олимпиада. У самого есть мысли, но хотелось бы узнать другие мнения.

Answer (score 1):

Одинаковые придаточные:  **На замечание, что перед едой надо мыть руки, мальчик ответил, что вымыл.**

Два изъяснительных придаточных.

Примечание

**Он бежал намного быстрее, чем бегал раньше, словно за ним кто-то гнался.** Это не совсем одинаковые придаточные: **сравнительно-сопоставительное и сравнительное**. Особенностью сравнительно-сопоставительных придаточных с союзом ЧЕМ...ТЕМ является наличие **сравнительной степени** прилагательного или наречия, которая является необходимым структурным элементом предложения.

Comment: Извините, Sibilla, я просто думаю, что к придаточному  изъяснительному не ставится вопрос от существительного, чаще  - от глагола. Здесь уместнее вопрос определительного придаточного.

Comment: В СПП с  определительными придаточными используются союзные слова, а здесь союз ЧТО. Опорными словами в СПП с придаточными изъяснительными могут быть не только глаголы, но и существительные.

Comment: Я об этом уже. думала. Ищу пример с союзом.

Comment: Разнёсся слух, что неприятель может вступить в город,

Comment: Согласна, что изъяснительное - более верно, что-союз. Значит, два предложения - 3 и 4

Comment: Да, наверное, что - то похожее.  Т. Драйзер: Нам остается только утешать себя мыслью (какой?), что эволюция человека никогда не прекратится. - Читайте подробнее на FB.ru: http://fb.ru/article/239840/opredelitelnoe-pridatochnoe-primeryi-predlojeniya-s-pridatochnyimi-opredelitelnyimi-primeryi

Comment: Нет, по - моему, в третьем первое всё - таки определительное. И верный ответ - 4. Мне так кажется

Comment: Нет, это тоже изъяснительное. Изъяснительные иногда относятся к существительным, соотносительным с глаголами типа заявление, известие, мысль, слух, сообщение. А определительное будет здесь: Слух, что (который) распространился по заводу, подтвердился.

Comment: Тем более, что в ответе 3 и 4, как сказали

Answer (score 0):

По - моему, в первом - придаточное степени и следствия: устал - в какой степени?, лёг спать - что из этого следует?
   Во втором - уступительное и изъяснительное:  не мог сосчитать - несмотря на что? сколько ни пытался; не мог сосчитать - что? сколько человек пришло
 В третьем - определительное на замечание - какое? -  определительное ,   мальчик ответил - что? - что вымыл  -  изъяснительное
 В четвёртом -  два сравнительных придаточных.
 А Вы, Aer, как считаете?
Поэтому, наверное, получится  в четвёртом - два  сравнительных. Я согласна полностью с Людмилой.  Я невнимательно прочитала вопрос и искала не в одном предложении два одинаковых придаточных, а два одинаковых вообще в тексте.

Comment: Я путаюсь в этих типах, так что, если можно, не буду позориться :)

Comment: Посмотрите, Aer, я добавила вопросы. Возможно, так?

Comment: Понял, что за вопросы. Спасибо за мнение!

Answer (score 0):

4.Он бежал намного быстрее, чем бегал раньше, словно за ним кто-то гнался.-**два придаточных сравнительных.**

Можно ещё подумать про это: 3.На замечание, что перед едой надо мыть руки, мальчик ответил, что вымыл. **Но** первое придаточное **определительное**-замечание какое? **с оттенком изъяснения** замечание о чём?

Так что только 4.

Comment: А как в ответе?

Comment: В ответе - 3 и 4.

Comment: Ну вот, а мы стараемся, доказываем

Comment: @user183861 так ответы без доказательств...